# regular file system that only allows for writing only one time

Tags: filesystems

Hello I have a quick question if someone could answer it for me.
In a write only one time system how can a person implement a read system on it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this, here is a simple overview of one.

A disc layout something like this:

```
0   root block -- identifies the file system, maybe a pointer to the end of metadata (n)
k   first data block -- contains data, possibly stale written to media.
l   last data block  -- last data block written.
m   last meta data block -- contains directories, inode tables, etc...
n   first meta data block -- contains initial directories, inodes, etc...
```

When the media is first accessed, the filesystem needs to determine where these values are.  A binary search of the media reveals where *l* and *m* and possible *n* are.  There is generally no way to find them otherwise.

Looking at the metadata [m..n] in this order, more recent versions of files are encountered at lower block addresses than older versions.  That is, the metadata grows from high to low addresses.  If you need to update some metadata, you need only scan forward until the first instance of it; and you can copy that instance, with your modifications, to block [m-1].

Note that not all the metadata for a file needs to be replaced; if it has 5 blocks of data pointers, and you have only changed one, only that block needs replaced.  Flexible tree structures help here.

The data doesn't matter so much; if you change a byte in block 3 of a file, the filesystem has to find where the pointer for block 3 is, and rewrite the tree of block pointers to reflect the new blocks.  If you look at a tradition (eg v7 unix filesystem) this will be obvious.  It works one more complex layouts, just harder to imagine.

If you were to execute code that did something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
      write(fd, str+i, 1);
      fsync(fd);
}
```

You might find your write-once media runs out of space pretty quickly; you would be committing at least a disk block per byte, and likely more like 3.  16k is a common disk block size for write only media, so that could be 48k per byte.

More frequently, the filesystem will hold of synchronizing the media until an idle period or only perform periodic snapshots from a log held in another media to prevent the pathological case above.

Many forms of write-once media aren't truly *write once*, rather each bit can be *set* or *cleared* once.  A block can be written multiple times, but only transitions in one directed actually take effect.  Also, many forms of media distinguish a *never written* block with a specific read error.  These abilities make for a more efficient write-once filesystem, as they allow things like state flags in the metadata.

Even if a true block-based *write once* media were in use, this can still be followed, just a little less efficiently.  For example, if an uninitialized block returned all zeros (or 0xffs), the file system could prefix each block with an identifier, reducing the efficiency of the IO, but permitting detection of uninitialized blocks.